# Lost memoir of Évariste Galois

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, reference-request, galois-theory, galois

According to the Wikipedia article on [Évariste Galois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89variste_Galois)

> He submitted his memoir on equation theory several times, but it was
> never published in his lifetime due to various events. Though his
> first attempt was refused by Cauchy, in February 1830 following
> Cauchy's suggestion he submitted it to the Academy's secretary Joseph
> Fourier, to be considered for the Grand Prix of the Academy.
> **Unfortunately, Fourier died soon after, and the memoir was lost.**

Abel's memoir was [lost in a similar circumstance](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5341/did-cauchy-forget-or-lose-mathematical-papers-aside-from-abels-and-galoiss) by Cauchy and Legendre some years prior to this incident and was only recovered partially, [until 2002 when the last few missing pages were also found](https://www.abelprize.no/nedlastning/litteratur/centina_parisan.pdf).

**Question: Similar to this, has Galois' lost memoir ever been found?**

Answer (score 4):

There have been several versions of the memoir. The last version was sent by Galois to his friend  [Auguste Chevallier](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/004/10/0093-0100).   just before the duel and was published by Camille Jordan. For details see the [book](https://ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=137).