# Citation of Brouwer needed

Tags: biographical-details

In a letter to Zeilberger the late Alexander Zenkin states that Brouwer called set theory "a pathological incident in history of mathematics from which future generations will be horrified". (See Doron Zeilberger: "Opinion 68" (2005)

I could not find the source. Where, if at all, did Brouwer say so?

Comment: Try looking in Dirk van Dalen's recent [biography of Brouwer](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1447146158). My copy is at home, by the way, or I'd try looking for it myself.

Comment: You can find it Zenkin, [Logic of Actual Infinity and Georg Cantor's Diagonal Proof of the Uncountability of the Continuum](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rml/1203431978), (2004) without direct reference.

Comment: Zenkin attributes it to A.A.Fraenkel & Y.Bar-Hillel, *Foundations of Set Theory* (1958 edition) where it is attributed generically to "the "Dutch school" (page 263).

Comment: The statement is not present in the [2nd 1973 edition](https://books.google.it/books?id=ah2bwOwc06MC&printsec=frontcover). Thus, the source is highly suspect...

Comment: A similar quote is attributed to Poincare, "*in the future set theory will be considered a disease from which one has recovered*", see [Did Poincaré say that set theory is a disease?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6038/55) Poincare actually talked about "beautiful pathological case" and with regard to self-referential definitions, not set theory as such. Quotes getting shifted from one author to another is usually a sign that they are made up, in this case to dramatize the opposition to Cantorian non-constructivism.

Comment: @Conifold: One of the characteristic features of **Cantorism** ... Hence the horror he has sometimes inspired in certain minds, such as Hermite's,...  certain paradoxes and apparent contradictions, which would have rejoiced the heart of Zeno of Elea and the school of Megara. ... For my part I think, and I am not alone in so thinking, that the important thing is never to introduce any entities but such as can be completely defined in a finite number of words. Whatever be the remedy adopted, we can promise ourselves the joy of the doctor called in to follow a fine pathological case. (Poincaré)

Comment: @Conifold:: There is no reason to dramatize the opposition. The drama exists. A mathematical theory that accepts and enforces the existence of undefinable numbers is nonsense. By the way, Cantor shared this opinion.

Comment: Apparently, there is. Here is the missing part of the horror quote:"*Hence the horror it sometimes inspired in certain minds, such as Hermite’s, whose favourite idea was to compare the mathematical with the natural sciences. **For most of us, these prejudices have been
dissipated**, but it has come about that we have run against
certain paradoxes...*" The remedy adopted was not Poincaré's but he wasn't horror struck by set theory, nor anticipated future generations to be. Neither did Brouwer. Cantor's theory does not require "existence" of *any* numbers, although he himself was a platonist.

Answer (score 4):

I have done a lot of research without any result. The quote is also given in "How Humans Learn to Think Mathematically: Exploring the Three Worlds of Mathematics" and asked the author by e-mail 3 days ago. There was no reply. I am convinced meanwhile that the quote is not authentic. If there will be any positive reaction I will edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is probably no authentic since Mückenheim, who is very careful in these matters, does not ascribe it to Brouwer in his Zenkin text quoted on p. 197 of [Transfinity](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~mueckenh/Transfinity/Transfinity/pdf).